# Как установить пароль на сайт которий лежит на хостинге?

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, hosts

Как установить пароль на сайт которий лежит на хостинге?
На сервере установлен Ubuntu с apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создай файл с паролем

```
htpasswd -c /home/username/example.com/.htpasswd user1
chmod 644 .htpasswd
```

получится такого вида: `user1:$apr1$bkS4zPQl$SyGLA9oP75L5uM5GHpe9A2`

Создай файл с правилом `.htaccess` с таким содержимым

```
#Protect Directory
AuthName "Введите пароль"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/username/example.com/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```